# Line spacing in book document class

Tags: line-spacing, preamble, books

how would I go about manipulating the line spacing in the preamble? I am using the 'book' document class.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean with "preamble"? Can you please add an example to your question tomake it clearer?

Comment: Hi and welcome, Package `setspace` is commonly used to change the line spacing of documents.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for all the responses. Do I simply write \setspace{} anywhere in the preamble?

Comment: @Johannes_B Do I need \usepackage{setspace}?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve, but `usepackage{setspace}` might be a good idea. and then `\onehalfspacing`. I really can't be more specific, as the question (currently) is very unclear.

Comment: @Johannes_B Where would I type \onehalfspacing? I'm trying to find a command or package so that I can manipulate the line spacing. So that I can try different values to see which line spacing makes my document look best.

Comment: Place it after calling the package.

Comment: Your document will probably look best with the standard spacing. Increasing spacing makes a document more and more ugly.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yeah you might be right. But sometimes too much maths looks a bit bunched, having said that I might find as you say that the standard spacing is better. But I will try \usepackage{setspace} and then \onehalfspacing. I'm hoping to find a command where you can really refine the spacing by inputting numerical values, is this not possible?

Comment: Of course it is, but with the limited information from your side, it is hard to suggest a robust solution. You are now talking about maths, this is a completely different field. Try to show us what you want to acieve with a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html) <- Link

Comment: @Johannes_B I mentioned the maths as a reason why more line spacing might look better.

Comment: The command in the `setspace` package is `\setstretch{value}`. But beware things are not as simple as one might think. For instance, ‘doublespacing’ does not mean `\setstretch{2}`, but a value which slightly varies with the font size, and is approximately `1.667`

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described in the comments above, you may use `setspace` package for adjusting line spacing.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\singlespacing
\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing
% or
%\setstretch{1.25}   %% change this number as you wish. 1.667 is double spacing.

\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If you don't want to use packages

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}
\def\baselinestretch{3}
\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{3\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If you want to complicate things further

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}
\newcommand{\setlinespacing}[1]%
           {\setlength{\baselineskip}{#1 \baselineskip}}
\def\baselinestretch{1}
\begin{document}
  \setlinespacing{3}   %% this is not triple line spacing
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Hope I have confused you enough with more complicated scenarios. Better use `setspace` package and live happy. :-)